# Compose-LazyVerticalGrid-Update list item properties on click

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazy-evaluation, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am having a lazy vertical grid which is rendered with a mutable list of items. i want alter the items properties in clicking in it.
Classes used:
Screen State

```
@Keep
data class ScreenState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    var items: MutableList<Item> = mutableListOf(),
    val error: String? = null,
    val endReached: Boolean = false,
    val page: Int = 0,
    val isInitialLoad : Boolean= true,
    val isEmpty:Boolean = false,
    val isFilterApplied:Boolean = false
)
```

List item data class:

```
@Keep
data class Item(
    val id:Int,
    var isLIked: Boolean = false,
    var name: String? = "",
    var desig: String = ",
    var imageUrl: String = "",
)
```

Inside viewModel: create a variable to store the state

```
var state by mutableStateOf(ScreenState())
```

On Api response success i am adding the items from json to the list of state object.

```
 state = state.copy(
                items = ((state.items + itemsFromResposne) as MutableList<AllDoctorsResponse.Data.Doctor>),
                page = newKey,
                endReached = items.isEmpty(),
                isEmpty = (state.page == 0 && items.isEmpty() )
            )
```

And adding this state.items in a lazy vertical grid

```
LazyVerticalGrid(                      //doctors list grid
            state = rememberLazyGridState(),
            cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            modifier = Modifier.zIndex(2f)
                .padding(top = 20.dp)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(17.dp),
            content = {
             itemsIndexed(screenState.items) { index, item
                 ListItemComposable(index,item,onclick-{

// Need the code to update item.liked = true from view model
})
               }

}
```

When the item is clicked i want to change the properties inside the list item object. But tits not rflecting in the screen on real time, but when its scrolled it gets recomposed and it gets reflected. How make it reflect and persist the state even when scrolled on and off .
Should i use a snapshot or please help how to do it.
This is code i used in viewmodel to update the item object

```
        viewModelScope.launch {
                            val alteredList = state.items.also {
                                it.forEach {
                                    if (it.id == item.id)
                                        it.liked = false
                                }
                            }
    }
 //add new list as all doctors list
                    state = state.copy(
                        items = alteredList
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Keep
data class Item(
    val id:Int,
    val isLiked: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false),
    var name: String? = "",
    var desig: String = "",
    var imageUrl: String = "",
)
```

Or

```
@Keep
class Item(
    val id:Int,
    isLiked: Boolean = false,
    var name: String? = "",
    var desig: String = "",
    var imageUrl: String = "",
){
    var isLiked by mutableStateOf(isLiked)
}
```

Comment: Did not work getiing this exception     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: @HarishPadmanabh Can you show how you instantiate an `Item` ?